# Structure JSON format to a specified data structure

Tags: python, json, data-structures

Basically I have a list

```
data_list = [
  '__att_names' : [
        ['id', 'name'], --> "__t_idx": 0
        ['location', 'address'] --> "__t_idx": 1
        ['random_key1', 'random_key2'] "__t_idx": 2
        ['random_key3', 'random_key4'] "__t_idx": 3
  ]
  "__root": {
      "comparables": [
            "__g_id": "153564396",
            "__atts": [
                1, --> This would be technically __att_names[0][1]
                'somerandomname',--> This would be technically __att_names[0][2]
                {
                    "__atts": [
                        'location_value', --> This would be technically __att_names[1][1]
                        'address_value',--> This would be technically __att_names[1][2]
                        "__atts": [
                        ]
                        "__t_idx": 1 --> It can keep getting nested.. further and further.
                    ]
                    "__t_idx": 1
                }
                {
                    "__atts": [
                        'random_key3value'
                        'random_key3value'
                    ]
                    "__t_idx": 3
                }
                {
                    "__atts": [
                        'random_key1value'
                        'random_key2value'
                    ]
                    "__t_idx": 2
                }
            ],
            "__t_idx": 0 ---> This maps to the first item in __att_names
    ]
  }
]
```

My desired output in this case would be

```
[
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'somerandomname',
        'location': 'address_value',
        'random_key1': 'random_key1value',
        'random_key2': 'random_key2value',
        'random_key3': 'random_key3value',
        'random_key4': 'random_key4value',
    }
]
```

I was able to get it working for the first few nested fields for __att_names, but my code was getting really long and wonky when I was doing nested and it felt really repetitive.
I feel like there is a neater and recursive way to solve this.

This is my current approach:
As of now the following code does take care first the very first nested object..

```
payload_names =  data_list['__att_names']
comparable_data = data_list['__root']['comparables']
output_arr = []
for items in comparable_data[:1]:
        output = {}
        index_number = items.get('__t_idx')
        attributes = items.get('__atts')
        if attributes:
            recursive_function(index_number, attributes, payload_names, output)
        output_arr.append(output)


def recursive_function(index, attributes, payload_names, output):
    category_location = payload_names[index]
    for index, categories in enumerate(category_location):
        output[categories] = attributes[index]
        if type(attributes[index]) == dict:
            has_nested_index = attributes[index].get('__t_idx')
            has_nested_attributes = attributes[index].get('__atts')
            if has_nested_attributes and has_nested_index:
                recursive_function(has_nested_index, has_nested_attributes, payload_names, output)
            else:
                continue
```

To further explain given example:

```
[ {
            'id': 1,
            'name': 'somerandomname',
            'location': 'address_value',
            'random_key1': 'random_key1value',
            'random_key2': 'random_key2value',
            'random_key3': 'random_key3value',
            'random_key4': 'random_key4value',
        }
    ]
```

Specifically `'location': 'address_value',` The value 'address_value' was derived from the array of `comparables` key which has the array of dictionaries with key value pair. i.e `__g_id` and `__atts` and also `__t_idx` note some of them might not have `__g_id` but when there is a key `__atts` there is also `__t_idx` which would map the index with array in `__att_names`

Overally
__att_names are basically all the different keys
and all the items within comparables -> __atts are basically the values for the key names in __att_names.

__t_idx helps us map `__atts` array items to `__att_names` and create a dictionary key-value as outcome.

Comment: Wrap your mapping code in a function, and call it recursively in the case  `if nested_attribute` is true

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, given your approach I attempted to create a recursive fucnction, however not all fields are properly mapped using _t_idx, can you validate the code for me? I updated the main thread.

Comment: I won't try to figure it out, sorry. Maybe somebody else will. But it's not clear to me how your payload definition leads you to get the key-value pair `'location': 'address_value',` out of your inputs; maybe clearing that up will help. But keep at it, test, and single-step your code in a debugger so you can watch it (you do have access to a debugger, I hope!)

Comment: No problem, I've updated the main post and added more context hopefully it's more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restructure a complex JSON object, my recommendation is to use `jq`.

- [Python package](https://pypi.org/project/jq/)
- [Oficial website](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

The data you present is really confusing and ofuscated, so I'm not sure what exact filtering your case would require. But your problem involves indefinitely nested data, for what I understand. So instead of a recursive function, you could make a loop that unnests the data into the plain structure that you desire. There's already a [question on that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54210566/while-unnesting-an-object-in-jq-how-can-i-avoid-restating-labels-at-each-stage).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `jq`! I couldn't say if this tool is the best fit for the OP (I suspect that a bit of hands-on wrangling in python might benefit them more), but I am definitely adding it to my toolbox.

Comment: PS could you add a `jq` script that can handle the nested data in the question (as far as we can understand what the OP is after, of course)?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have enough experience with `jq` to elaborate such filter... I myself discovered a few time ago, and although I'm 100% that it can be a solution, I'm not able to write it right now. However, the structure would be the one a said: a loop or a recursive function that, while there is nested data, filters it and adds it to a separate array.

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the structure while tracking the `__t_idx` key values that correspond to list elements that are not dictionaries:

```
data_list = {'__att_names': [['id', 'name'], ['location', 'address'], ['random_key1', 'random_key2'], ['random_key3', 'random_key4']], '__root': {'comparables': [{'__g_id': '153564396', '__atts': [1, 'somerandomname', {'__atts': ['location_value', 'address_value', {'__atts': [], '__t_idx': 1}], '__t_idx': 1}, {'__atts': ['random_key3value', 'random_key4value'], '__t_idx': 3}, {'__atts': ['random_key1value', 'random_key2value'], '__t_idx': 2}], '__t_idx': 0}]}}
def get_vals(d, f = False, t_idx = None):
   if isinstance(d, dict) and '__atts' in d:
       yield from [i for a, b in d.items() for i in get_vals(b, t_idx = d.get('__t_idx'))]
   elif isinstance(d, list):
       yield from [i for b in d for i in get_vals(b, f = True, t_idx = t_idx)]
   elif f and t_idx is not None:
       yield (d, t_idx)

result = []
for i in data_list['__root']['comparables']:
    new_d = {}
    for a, b in get_vals(i):
       new_d[b] = iter([*new_d.get(b, []), a])
    result.append({j:next(new_d[i]) for i, a in enumerate(data_list['__att_names']) for j in a})

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[
   {'id': 1, 
    'name': 'somerandomname', 
    'location': 'location_value', 
    'address': 'address_value', 
    'random_key1': 'random_key1value', 
    'random_key2': 'random_key2value', 
    'random_key3': 'random_key3value', 
    'random_key4': 'random_key4value'
    }
]
```

Comment: I was able to get it working, the dictionaries does seem like it's properly mapping however, it appears that this only gives me one dictionary back. I wanted to create a dictionary for EACH item within ['comparalales'] array.

Comment: for a, b in get_vals(data_list['__root']): I tried changing this to data_list['__root']['comparables'] no luck'

Comment: What I am saying is that, there could be a list of comparables, as of now it only seem to be doing it for the first item in comparable list.

Comment: After spending some time with the code snippet you sent me, I see one issue, the code takes care of properly assigning t_index to the list of items that are not dictionaries, but t_index, but also have a dictionary as value themselves, it just won't have __atts key name to it. I tried fixing it with the existing code you sent me, no luck. The issue right now is the names `__att_names` don't exactly match the data retrieved by get_vals, the length's are different, and that is because we skip those dictionaries with no __att_names key. @Ajax1234

Comment: @HOOOPLA To clarify, `__t_idx` can take a dictionary, as opposed to an `int`? Also, `__att_names` and `__atts` might not appear in a given dictionary?

Comment: @HOOOPLA Please see my recent edit, I added a check to ensure that every dictionary traversed in `get_vals` has an `__atts` key

Comment: So to clarify: items within _atts could be either string, int or dictionary themselves. 
When there is a dictionary within  `__atts` list,  it can have the key `t_index` or it won't. If it doesn't, than we know those dictionaries need to be yielded to the t_index. To better understand data structure, I've created a paste for it https://pastebin.com/xiwjASt4, this only includes first item in the array data_list['__root']['comparables'][:1]

Comment: i.e for __t_idx 0, it yelds 0: [generator] --, the items in the generator doesn't equal the items found in __att_names[0], the length of  __att_names[0] [
                "custom",
                "listingIsPrimary",
                "personal",
                "listing",
                "editableHomeFact",
                "extra",
                "property"
            ] 

The array includes exactly 6 items, but our generator returns 3 items, that is because it skips the dictionaries.